# TikZ-Editor: Preview error

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, editors, mactex

How can I setup my [TikZ-Editor](https://github.com/fredokun/TikZ-Editor) to enable preview?

I use MacTeX 2013, installed with the ISO file.

Could you give me some clue about how I can configure this software?

The error message reads:

> Preview Error: Can't convert the source file to PDF. Please check the LaTeX command in preview's preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error messages says that the LaTeX command is incorrect, which it is by default (more or less). You either could chang your global path variable in a way that TikZ-editor finds `pdflatex`, or you tell TikZ-Editor where `pdflatex` is installed. WIth MacTeX, the command should be

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory $OUTPUT_DIR -jobname $FILE_NAME $FILE_PATH
```

[image: change the latex command]

Answer (score 3):

Tobi's solution didn't work for me until I got rid of the quotation marks. I.e., instead of `"/usr/texbin/pdflatex"` use `/usr/texbin/pdflatex`.

Answer (score 3):

The `pdflatex` executable wasn't in `/usr/texbin/pdflatex` on my system. A more general approach would be to locate the file on your system by typing the following command in terminal on Mac:

```
which pdflatex
```

On Windows the command would be `where pdflatex`

It then gives you the path to `pdflatex`, which in may case was:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```